# How can I "concatenate" a column even if it's empty?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has the following columns (sender_id, reciever_id, messages) the messages column takes in a json object that looks like this:

```
[{"message":"final in numbers","sender":"test","reciever":"try"}]
```

Currently, I'm able to **UPDATE** the messages column with new messages objects, using this query:

```
"UPDATE chats SET messages = $1 WHERE sender_id = $2 AND reciever_id = $3",
```

The problem with this, is that it removes the previous value stored at messages and updates it with the new one. This is a problem, I don't want to lose the previous values/messages/objects.

I found a way to solve this using concatenation

```
UPDATE chats SET messages = messages || $1 WHERE sender_id = $2 AND reciever_id = $3
```

The problem with this is that it only concatenate if there is at least one json object in the messages column, if it's empty, I won't get any errors, but the value doesn't get added.

Is there a way I can fix this, so that I can add to an empty column, but also not lose the objects when a new sessions is started.

I know I can probably glue something using if statements in my code, but I feel like that's overcomplicating it.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data that is giving you problems, and expected output?

Comment: Your example shows an array with an object, not an object alone. At any rate: `select coalesce(null, '[]'::jsonb) || '[1,2,3]'::jsonb; [1, 2, 3]` or `select coalesce(null, '{}'::jsonb) || '{"1": 1,"2": 2,"3": 3}'::jsonb;  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}`

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: "*the messages column holds a json array of objects*" - just don't do that. Normalise your database schema, and store each message in its own table row. Problem solved.

Comment: Spelling error: It's "receiver", not "reciever". When naming tables and columns, it's really important to check your spelling because it's a mistake you sometimes have to live with forever. I once worked with a database (that was defined by people whose first language was not English) with `question` and `anwser` tables the spelling of which we couldn't correct due to change control and a lot of the code base having poured concrete around the error.

Comment: @lemon  I explained it in the post, where I showed the object I'm trying to add to my database, if that object already exists in my database under the messenger column, I can concatenate new objects to it, without losing the values that already exist in there. But when I try to concat an obj whilst the column is empty, nothing gets added, and no errors either. This is expected I assume, but if so how can I add new objects to my jsonb column without losing the existing ones .

Comment: @Bohemian  I spelled it reciever throughout the whole project for some reason. I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't provide help on problems that miss input or output data - unless they're very basic tasks - because I can't ensure tested and solid solutions and it would most likely result in a waste of (my and your) time.

Comment: @lemon ok I understand. Just ignore the post I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
UPDATE chats SET messages = COALESCE(messages || $1, $1) WHERE sender_id = $2 AND reciever_id = $3
```

Comment: Better: `COALEASE(messages, '[]') || $1`. But really if this solution is working, the actual problem is that the default value of the `messages` column is `NULL` where it should have been `[]`. Fixing that (and adding a `NOT NULL` constraint) would be better than changing the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really nice solution, and a powerful function. I just learned about how it works. 
if anyone is interested. This is how it works 

it first checks if the value of the messages column is NULL or not. If it's not NULL, it concatenates the value of messages with the value of $1. If messages is NULL, the function returns the value of $1. It's similar to a  ternary operator if you think about it.